# How should I enable my AdMob real ID's in Google Play Console?

Tags: java, android, production, google-play-console

Ok here is the situation. This is my first app, developed in Android Studio, and everything has worked out fine in the internal, alpha and beta phases. Now I want to get into production. But...as far as I know is against the rules to use real Ads in test scenarios.

So, when should I replace the test Id's for the real ones? If I replace it and upload the signed APK for the production release, wouldn't it be tested by the google "bots" for testing purposes. Wouln't my account be suspended in that case?

What would be the best way to release to production with the real Ads?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the release version, you can update the ID of the ad.

it will not affect the google testing